# Change style of single feature in mapbox gl

Tags: mapbox-gl, mapbox-gl-js

The examples for highlighting polygons in mapbox gl use a second layer and a filter function. Is it not possible to change the color of a single feature/polygon in mapbox gl js, drawn from geojson source?

See https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/hover-styles/

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to style a single feature using a data driven style that responds uniquely to an attribute of a single feature. For instance, if you have a point dataset with an `id` attribute and you want id 450 to be yellow instead of blue.

```
{
  "id": "mypoints",
  "type": "circle",
  "paint": {
    "fill-color": {
      "property": "id",
      "type": "category",
      "stops": [[450, "yellow"]],
      "default": "blue"
    }
  }
}
```

Caveat 1: the "default" feature is [not publicly available yet](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/pull/4175).

Caveat 2: This only works for style properties that support data-driven functions.

Comment: The key part of my question is CHANGE the polygon style, not set the polygon style. I want to be able to change an individual feature/polygon on the fly, not when the style is initially created. Can I do that with this method?

Comment: Yes, that's what [data-driven styling](https://www.mapbox.com/blog/data-driven-styling/) is. You can leave the data the same, and update the style to highlight a different bit of it.

Comment: yes, but how do you call that...layer.setStyle()? because there is nothing in the docs that shows how to update the style of a layer that I can find other than adding a new layer...I must be missing something here as this seems like a basic feature

Comment: That changes/reloads the entire map, right? I am thinking more traditional GIS with a basemap as my map style, then layers on top. It looks like this works with map.setPaintProperty() with using stops function.

Comment: Not sure I understand you. `setStyle` changes one layer. `setPaintProperty` changes one property of one layer (as does `setLayoutProperty`). Both are potentially extremely quick - there's no "reloads the entire map".

Comment: Currently, the feature highlighting on click feels faster in my leaflet vector grid parcel viewer app compared to the mapbox gl js version, using the same vector tiles. I was trying to find a faster way to highlight an individual feature in mapbox gl js, but this does not seem possible. I'll provide examples soon.