# change single feature of layer mapbox JS

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

I am beginner in mapbox js. I am looking for a way to update a single feature of layer in mapbox JS. I would like to change at any time color of my single feature. I want to manage this manually. Color will depend on a value from DB arrives from socket. There is a function setPaintProperty, but this is for whole layer. Anybody know is there any possibility to change color single feature like this?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42282533/change-style-of-single-feature-in-mapbox-gl